# How to add filters in jhipster gateway?

Tags: jhipster, gateway

I'm using jhipster micro services. Is there anyway to add pre- and post-filters as that in the springCloud?

Answer (score 1):

Yes because a JHipster gateway embeds a zuul proxy so refer to spring cloud docs like https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html and https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/ .

You can also find few examples in generated code of your gateway: `TokenRelayFilter`, `AccessControlFilter`, `RateLimitingFilter`, etc...